I need more current than an LM1117/NCP1117 at 5V can provide (i.e > 1A)
I've got a simple power supply circuit to power-up some old-school TTL & seven-segment display boards (legacy computer front panel stuff).
My first built for the 5V supply was with an NCP1117 (i.e. LM1117) which is rated at 1A. So far so good. As I bring more and more of the legacy board up; I'm realizing these old chips take a lot more power than I budgeted (this is normal for 74xx from the 80's/90's).

There's additional caps on both inbound and outbound side (not shown on this snippet).
I'm feeding this with 7.5 volts presently and I'm already up to 1/2 Amps worth of usage with plenty more chips to enable. While this is a nice and efficient supply (and better than the LM317 I first used (i.e 1117 runs way-cooler!), I'm in need of at-least 2.5 Amps pretty soon. What's next after the 1117?
I'd like recommendations that match the 1117's efficiency. Plan A is to split the old-school logic into separate areas and feed them each with their own dedicated 1117 supply; however, that's not a great use of PCB space (or $$'s).
Recommendations?
Thanks in advance.

Why would you want to match the 1117's efficiency? Even a super-basic switching converter can vastly exceed its efficiency, and you can get ones in little modules that can just be drop-in replacements.

Linear regulators are a good choice when you need a small amount of current or when you need extremely low noise and don't mind being inefficient, but they're a terrible choice for a high current digital application which is why you see buck converters for computer supply rails.

The real question is: how exactly are you getting to 0.5A with just TTL (assuming 74HC stuff) and the occasional 7 seg? Are you powering the 7 seg with 20mA per segment or some such?

@Lundin - This is all classic "74" series ("74LS" pseudo equivalent) and sadly not "74HC". I'm still bring up stuff; but it looks like 50+ 74xx's, leds, seven segment, buzzer, etc. Even at 15mA per 74xx chip (which a middle of the road 7474 is rated at), I'm .75 A. Add .5 A for the LED's, then .4 A for the R.Pi.Zero2W running the whole thing and I'm pushing 1.65 A and hence by adding a margin, I'm at 2.5 A. BTW: I know this is a worse case calculation - but that's why I've already blown my 1 A initial design.

You can stick with the 1117 by adding an external pass transistor to provide any current beyond the limit imposed by the regulator IC:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When current drawn via the regulator U1 reaches about 0.5A, the voltage across R1 rises to 0.7V or so, which switches on transistor Q1. Any extra current required by the load (R2 here) comes via Q1 instead.
You are mistaken about the 1117 running cooler than the LM317. There may be some differences regarding how heat is removed from the regulator (how it's mounted, for example), but the two would dissipate the same power.
In the design above, the regulator will be dissipating \$P_{U1}\$:
$$ P_{U1} = (7.5V -0.7V - 5V) \times 0.5A = 0.9W $$
Q1 will dissipate \$P_{Q1}\$:
$$ P_{Q1} = (7.5V - 5V) \times I_{Q1} $$
With a load current of 2A, so that Q1 carries \$ I_{Q1} = 2A - 0.5A = 1.5A \$:
$$ P_{Q1} = (7.5V - 5V) \times 1.5A = 3.8W $$
Q1 will require heat sinking.

Thank you - that's an interesting option. I note from the other answers that I could still go with a single chip solution (i.e. XL4016) or a module approach (which I'm starting to see value in). I'll build up your design and play with it.

I suggest using one of the ubiquitous switching power supply devices that are designed to replace a linear regulator such as the LM7805 or LM1117. You can then use a 12V supply. Here for example, is a CUI one (but only 500mA). Murata makes some as well (1.5A for this one).
While they do not match the efficiency of the LM1117, as requested, they are generally way better (perhaps 90%+) compared to 65%-ish so a fraction of the heating and a 2A 12V wall wart could give you 5V at 3A or 4A at the regulator output.
There are also very inexpensive adjustable buck regulator modules available on the hobby market based on cloned LM2576 or similar chips, however you may not wish to trust them. Also some beefier ones based on the XLSEMI XL4016.

Thank you. The XL4016 looks very interesting and there's a lot of reference designs out there using it (after I started looking). It also shows up on pre-build module - which I had not thought about using. I'll go build one and see how I like that chip. Thanks for the other ideas also.
